# Does Vanilla EOS 5.1 Support USB Ethernet Dongle

Tags: ethernet

does vanilla EOS 5.1 support internet using a USB Ethernet Dongle?

Background: Chuwi Herobook 14.1 laptop. Need to install RealTek 8821CE driver for wifi to work. Need internet to install. No ethernet port!!

Hence the question.

(If the answer is you have to first apt install  before it will work, then I need more instructions because I have no wifi, no net to start with)

Thanks

(Is there a better way to solve my problem?)

Comment: Connect your smartphone using USB cable and use USB tethering. eOS will connect automatically, without any setup needed.

Comment: Thanks!  That's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found a better way!  I don't need wifi dongle to get this to work.

Recap of the real background issue:

Chuwi Herobook 14.1 laptop. Need to install RealTek 8821CE driver for wifi to work. Need internet to install. No ethernet port!!

Since I have dual boot Windows 10 and EOS, I can download the required driver and dependent packages in the Windows 10 OS.  Write them to a USB stick.  Then boot EOS and download the files from USB.  (I presume a shared partition will definite work... but I chose the easier route, easier for me)

For others having the same problem... I saved the files in github:

See https://github.com/bryanso/chuwi_eos_5.1 if interested.